How to add dependency to gitlab ci/cd jobs?
I would like to execute test-job2 , only if test-job1 succeeds. how can i configure such that test-job2 gets fired , as soon as test-job1 finishes and with a success.
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 mydumbscript.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3


test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20



You can make use of needs keyword to set up the dependency.
In your case, you need to add needs: test-job1 under your test-job2.
test-job2:
  stage: test
  needs: test-job1
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

Note: This works for both GitLab and GitHub.

thanks. I apologize for this, but one follow up question. If i am running the entire pipeline, then i test-job2 only run if test-job1 succeeds, which can be achieved by needs keyword. but i would like to independently trigger just the test-job2 via api . is this possible, to have both use cases?

@kishi I'm not aware if this is actually possible or not. If you think its important enough for you, perhaps its better if you ask as another question, so that others with more experience may provide a better answer.
